# Can't open mkl_intel_s_dll.lib in 64bit Visual Studio environment

Tags: c++, 64-bit, intel-mkl

I tried to compile in Visual studio 2013 for some program using mkl.

It works fine in 32bit environment. But in 64 bit they say

> error LNK1181 :Can not open 'mkl_intel_s.lib'
>       error #11018: Cannot open mkl_intel_s_dll.lib
>       error $11018: Cannot open mkl_intel_s.lib

I already download all files from parallel studio

And when I copy and paste `mkl_intel_s_dll.lib` and `mkl_intel_s.lib` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE\mkl\lib\ia32`
to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE\mkl\lib\intel64` directory, they succeed in compiling but output program doesn't work properly.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The copying you are doing is definitely the wrong approach, you're mixing 32 and 64 bit libraries (amazing no linker errors ensue, actually). Did you (properly) install both the 32 and 64 bit versions of MKL. Did you select to use MKL in the (64 bit) projects' properties settings (Intel Performance Libraries)?

If you overwrote the files that pre-existed before in the intel64 directory, you should un-install and re-install MKL, using the installer. (This might fix your problem as well).